# How to mimic SAS PROC SCORE function in Python

Tags: python, model, sas, prediction, proc

I have a score file generated from SAS PROC REG function, which has the information of model parameters and their coefficients.

I need to use the parameter and coefficient information in the score file to calculate the predictions on a data frame in Python. The Python prediction results should match with the SAS PROC SCORE results. Could anyone give me  suggestions/examples on how to do this in Python?

Very appreciate for your help!